# How to see all incoming requests to my server?

Tags: logging, connection

I have a third party app and I would like to see how it communicates with the server.
Why kind of software/server I am supposed to run to log all possible connections attempts to all possible ports? (let's assume, that it could be https connections, telnet, socket opening etc.)

Answer (score 1):

Wireshark, tshark, simple tcpdump,smokeping, iPerf. If you need a graphical representation use Cacti and RRDtool together.